# Different between PHP md5 and JAVA md5

Tags: java, php, md5

I define a md5 function in JAVA and use PHP:md5() function to encode,but they output different results.

I guess there's something wrong with my JAVA function.

Here's the code:

```
public static String MD5Encode(String sourceString) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] bytes = md.digest();
    StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer(bytes.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        if ((bytes[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            bf.append("0");
        }
        bf.append(Long.toString(bytes[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
    return bf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String MD5Encode(String sourceString) {
try {
byte[] bytesOfMessage = sourceString.getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
// byte array of md5 hash
byte[] md5 = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
// we convert bytes to hex as php's md5() would do
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < md5.length; i++) {
stringBuffer.append(Integer.toString((md5[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 
16).substring(1));
}
return stringBuffer.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: PHP 's md5() function returns the md5 hash as a hex.
If you want to get the md5 hash as string in java you can write like this